# Error in displaying retrieved JSON content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

In continuation to my question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212105/how-to-get-and-display-the-list-of-youtube-videos-using-javascript), i have created a test app to check the json parsing using jquery. 
It doesnt seem to work. I can append data in the click function. However getting data from that url and parsing seems to fail. Can someone provide some useful hints?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>jffnfjnkj</ul></div>");
    $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?callback=function&alt=jsonc&v=2", function(data) {
        var dataContainer = $("#data ul");
        $.each(data.data.items, function(i, val) {
         $("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>jffnfjnkj</ul></div>");
if (typeof(val.player) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.title) !== 'undefined') {
dataContainer.append("<li><a href = "+val.player.default+" target = '_blank'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");
        }
        });
        });


  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Header</h2>
<p>Paragrapgh</p>
<p>Paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

TIA,
Praveen S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback is provided so that you can bypass the same origin policy. Thus retrieved JSON data is enclosed within the function name and cannot be parsed directly. Details of doing this with jquery are given [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Please refer the example given below

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
         url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?',
         dataType: "jsonp",
         timeout: 5000,
         success: function(data){
                    alert(data.apiVersion);
                    //add your JSON parsing code here
                  }

 });

</script>
```

Please find the working example [here](http://tallymobile.com/test7.html).

Comment: Can you try it in your browser? I am new to this whole web-development. I want to know if the url is wrong or the code.

Comment: Sure, I'll test this and revert. The url is correct, try copying and pasting the url in the address bar and see for yourself.

Comment: Praveen, please see the code to handle the JSONP request. This should address your problem. Let me know in case you still face any issues. Cheers

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code. I can now parse and get the title. Can you give me some links where i can learn how to get all elements from a json response. In my prev question there was a link from which i fetched the val.title variable but how to get other details and how to create a html body using the response? TIA.

Comment: Praveen, I've added the working example of your code. JSON in javascript can intrinsically be resolved down to arrays and/or objects. For parsing them, you need to know the document structure of the JSON that you are receiving. In the case of youtube this document can be found here http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html

Answer (score 0):

the url does not return a json like you would like try without the     `callback=function`
with the callback it uses a method called jsonp:
http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding