# how to load a carousel from a xml file?

Tags: iphone, xml, appcelerator, carousel

I'd like to load a carousel from a xml file and put it in the middle of a window and below the carousel I have a view that contains the description of each image.

kind when I scroll the images I have every description of this picture that I'm also recovering from an xml file

Can you tell me how I could do?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "carousel" ? An image showing a carousel ?

Comment: a carousel is a set of images you can scroll

Here is an example http://davy-leggieri.developpez.com/tutoriels/android/creation-carrousel/

Answer (score 0):

[AQGridview](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) will help you create the carousel. However you have to parse your xml and get the datastore yourself using [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer

I notice it in xcode as I'm working with Appcelerator

Comment: Well then you can write up a javascript piece of code to do it. http://blarnee.com/wp/jquery-image-carousels-for-slidehow/comment-page-1/

Comment: the problem is not how to create a carousel that I can do but using images I locally but now I want to load images from an xml file and I do not know how I could take

Comment: Have you considered parsing your xml file using jquery?

Comment: can you give me an example of using please. because then I really started with javascript and Appcelerator

Comment: Hope this question will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212105/how-to-get-and-display-the-list-of-youtube-videos-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Titanium APIs that you'll need to use to achieve what you want. There are plenty of examples in the [Kitchen Sink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink) demo application that Titanium provide.

Firstly, you'll need to use the [Titanium Filesystem](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Filesystem-module) module to read your XML file into a string. There's an example of that [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/filesystem.js).

Secondly, once you have the XML string you can use the [XML module](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.XML-module) to parse it and extract the data you need for your carousel. Assuming within the XML you have paths to images hosted remotely on a server, you'd need to add these to an array or something. There's an example of working with XML in Titanium [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/xml_dom.js).

Finally, once you have an array of image paths you can use them with one of the UI components like [ScrollableView](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-object) or [CoverFlow](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.CoverFlowView-object). With CoverFlow it's as easy as providing your image array to the component:

```
var view = Titanium.UI.createCoverFlowView({
    images:['a.png','b.png','c.png'],
    backgroundColor:'#000'
});
window.add(view);
```

With the ScrollableView you'd need to create ImageViews for each of your images, then add them to the View.

There's a CoverFlow example [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/coverflow_remote.js) and a ScrollableView example [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/scroll_views_scrollable.js).

Comment: I would use the `scrollableView` opposed to the `coverFlow` because it's supported on both iPhone/iOS and android where as the `coverFlow` is just iPhone/iOS.

Comment: thank you for your answer

I'll try to do anything but C would have been better if you could post a small example

thank you

Comment: I've linked to lots of examples in my answer. What don't you understand?